# Keep new lines from textbox when sending Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, textbox

I would like the user to fill out the textbox and for their input to be displayed, with the separated lines, the same way when I send it through outlook. Currently the value of the textbox is being reformatted by removing new lines when it gets transferred to outlook. Does ".HTMLBody" property ignore separate lines?

Here is a screenshot of how the information is entered into the textbox.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of how the information is displayed in outlook.

[image]

What are my options to have the new lines in the text box message stay when the value of the textbox is used outlook? Here is the code I'm using to do that.

```
Dim message As String

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

message = tbScript

With olEmail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = message
    .To = "test@gmail.com"
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: What is `tbScript`?

Comment: `.HTMLBody = Replace(message, vbLf, "<br>")`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz that's the name of the textbox from the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTML in general ignores line breaks. You need to replace line breaks with `<br>` tags.

Or, since you are setting to a plaintext value anyway, set the plaintext `MailItem.Body` property instead of `MailItem.HTMLBody`.